# who calls .bashrc

Tags: bashrc, mint

On linux mint mate, I have a .bashrc file in my home folder, but I didn't see any of:

```
1 ~/.bash_profile
2 ~/.bash_login
3 ~/.profile
```

So who calls `.bashrc` when I open a new terminal window?

And, if I create a new system user, does `~/.bashrc` work? Or it only works for normal user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a `.bashrc` file in my home folder, but I didn't see any.

Open a terminal and Try `ls -la ~/.bashrc` to see it.

> who calls .bashrc when I open a new terminal window?

It is bash shell initialization file. BASH call it.

Comment: I saw `.bashrc`, I don't know who calls it. So bash program always call it when init a new terminal? Ok, I didn't know that.

Comment: By the way, I just did a test it works for both normal user & system user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fresh install of Linux Mint, .bashrc file might not be there. You can create a new one with 
`touch ~/.bashrc` and specify your settings and variables.

Since the `.bashrc` is created in the user's home directory it's user specific. If you create a new user you'll have to set up another appropriate `.bashrc` file.

Variables and settings you specify in the `.bashrc` file will be loaded everytime you open a bash terminal.

Comment: I do soft link of existing `.bashrc` when create a new user.